# Why doesn't the compiler perform a type conversion?

Tags: c++, operators, type-conversion

Consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct SimpleStruct
{
    operator std::string () { return value; }
    std::string value;
};

int main ()
{
    std::string s;    // An empty string.
    SimpleStruct x;   // x.value constructed as an empty string.

    bool less = s < x; // Error here.
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile either on g++ or Microsoft Visual C++. The error report given by compilers is `no match for operator '<' in 's < x'`. The question is why does the compiler not simply convert the `SimpleStruct x` to `string` according to the given `operator string ()` and then use `operator < ( string, string )`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`operator<` for `std::string` is a function template. The overloads are:

```
  template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
    bool operator< (const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
            const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
  template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
    bool operator< (const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
            const charT* rhs);
  template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
    bool operator< (const charT* lhs,
            const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
```

Your call doesn't match any of the available overloads, so they are all removed from a list of candidates. Since no function template was picked as a candidate for resolving the call, there is nothing to convert SimpleStruct to.

```
template <class T>
class String
{
};

template <class T>
bool operator< (const String<T>&, const String<T>&) { return true; }


//if a suitable non-template function is available, it can be picked
//bool operator< (const String<char>&, const String<char>&) { return true; }

struct SimpleStruct
{
   operator String<char> () { return value; }
   String<char> value;
};

int main()
{
    String<char> s;
    SimpleStruct ss;
    s < ss; //the call doesn't match the function template, leaving only the commented-out candidate
}
```

Comment: +1, this answer is correct. `string::operator <()` doesn't take argument as `const string&`, but `basic_string<>`; if you overload `operator <` globally then it works. http://www.ideone.com/vMERa

Comment: Eh, `std::string` is just a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. `typedef` doesn't introduce a new type, and therefore doesn't affect overloading.

Comment: The underlying problem is that the deduction of `charT` in `template<class charT, class tr, class Alloc> bool operator< (std::basic_string<charT, tr,Alloc> const& lhs, std::basic_string<charT, tr, Alloc> const& rhs);` fails. There's no `charT` for which `basic_string<charT>` _equals_ `SimpleStruct`. That indeed removes it from the overload set.