# C++ Implicit Conversion Operators Precedence

Tags: c++, casting, operator-precedence, conversion-operator

EDIT: Following Mike Seymour's comment, I replaced `operator std::string () const;` with `operator char * () const;` and changed the implementation accordingly. This allows implicit casting, but, for some reason, the unsigned long int operator has precedence over the char * operator, which just does not feel right... Also, I don't want to expose nasty C stuff like char * outside the class, when I have std::string. I have a hunch that my CustomizedInt class needs to inherit from some stuff in order to support the feature that I desire. Could anybody please elaborate Mike's comment regarding `std::basic_string`? I'm not sure I understood it properly.

---

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class CustomizedInt
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    CustomizedInt() : data(123)
    {
    }
    operator unsigned long int () const;
    operator std::string () const;
};

CustomizedInt::operator unsigned long int () const
{
    std::cout << "Called operator unsigned long int; ";
    unsigned long int output;
    output = (unsigned long int)data;
    return output;
}

CustomizedInt::operator std::string () const
{
    std::cout << "Called operator std::string; ";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << this->data;
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    CustomizedInt x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints "Called operator unsigned long int; 123". My questions are these:

1. After I remove the operator unsigned long int, why do I need to cast x to std::string explicitly? Why does it not call the implicit cast operator (std::string) directly?
2. Is there any documentation that explains which implicit casts are allowed and which is their order of precedence? It seems that if I add an operator unsigned int to this class together with the operator unsigned long int, I receive a compiler error about ambiguity for the << operator...
3. Also, I know that defining such an operator may be poor practice, but I am not sure I fully understand the associated caveats. Could somebody please outline them? Would it be better practice to just define public methods ToUnsignedLongInt and ToString?

Comment: This is related: [Overload resolution failure when streaming object via implicit conversion to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677072/overload-resolution-failure-when-streaming-object-via-implicit-conversion-to-str)

Comment: @Als: Let's take it slowly... I'm not prepared to dive into templates yet :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After I remove the operator unsigned long int, why do I need to cast x to std::string explicitly? Why does it not call the implicit cast operator (std::string) directly?

The version of `<<` for strings is a template, parametrised by the parameters of the `std::basic_string` template (`std::string` itself being a specialisation of that template). It can only be chosen by argument-dependent lookup, and that only works if the argument is actually a specialisation of `std::basic_string`, not something convertible to that.

> Is there any documentation that explains which implicit casts are allowed and which is their order of precedence?

The rules are quite complex, and you'd need to read the C++ standard for the full story. Simple rules of thumb are that implicit conversions can't contain more than one user-defined conversion and (as you've found out) the result of an implicit conversion can't be used to choose a template specialisation by argument-dependent lookup.

> I am not sure I fully understand the associated caveats. Could somebody please outline them?

I don't fully understand them either; the interactions between implicit conversions, name lookup and template specialisation (and probably other factors that I can't think of right now) are rather complex, and most people don't have the inclination to learn them all. There are quite a few instances where implicit conversion won't happen, and others where it might happen when you don't expect it; personally, I find it easier just to avoid implicit conversions most of the time.

> Would it be better practice to just define public methods ToUnsignedLongInt and ToString?

That's probably a good idea, to avoid unwanted conversions. You can fix your problem by leaving them and use them explicitly when necessary:

```
std::cout << std::string(x) << std::endl;
```

In C++11, you can declare them `explicit`, so that they can only be used in this manner. In my opinion, that would be the best option if you can; otherwise, I would use explicit conversion functions as you suggest.

By the way, the return type of `main()` must be `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Mike: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed comment. It does clear up things a bit. Also, thanks for spotting that small issue with "void main". I should remember to use the correct version, no matter what :)