# Implicit type conversion is not working

Tags: c++

```
class Test {
public:
    operator string() {
        return string{"TEST!"};
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << Test{};
}
```

I was expecting the Test object will be implicit converted to a string and output, but it gives me error:

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

This explicit conversion works:

```
cout << string{Test{}};
```

---

I got it working by casting to `const char*`:

```
class Test {
public:
    operator const char*() {
        return "TEST!";
    }
};
```

Then output:

```
cout << Test{}; //Yay it works.
```

I am assuming the `cout << string` is already an implicit conversion from `string` to `char *` and if I use casting to string, it will not perform a two level conversion from `Test to string to char *`. After directly casting to `const char*`, it works. (Please correct if the assumption is wrong)

---

**TO PROVE THE ASSUMPTION IS RIGHT**

```
class Test {
public:
    operator string() {
        return string{"TEST!"};
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, string s){
    os << s;
    return os;
}
```

This will perform a direct type deduction from `Test to string` and output string. and after I tried, it works!

```
cout << Test{}; //YAY WORKS! OUTPUT "TEST!"
```

---

**Something special about `cout << string` is explained by `Borgleader`. Assumption is partially correct and partially wrong.**

Comment: You've got your definitions of explicit and implicit switched. `T{x}` *explicitly* specifies a `T`, just `x` alone does not. Your first line would *implicitly* convert to a `string`.

Comment: @GManNickG yeah they always confused me.. Edited.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539555/why-does-outputting-a-class-with-a-conversion-operator-not-work-for-stdstring

Comment: Your assumptions at the end are wrong. There is no implicit conversion from `string` to `(const) char *`. Neither does `cout << some_string` call `cout << some_string.c_str()` internally. [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=577ff2fa377ec4b96acb609d3e2134cb-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62) proof of that; printing the string prints past the embedded NULL character. The `const char *` conversion operator works because `operator<<(ostream, const char *)` is not a function template. So it makes it into the overload resolution set, and is chosen as a viable match.

Comment: @chris If I use `os<<s`, it will recur until it crashes...

Comment: It's worth noting you're not allowed to overload `operator<<` to take `std::string` (this *also* came up in the linked dupe, so I suggest reading it if you haven't). I was assuming you meant to take a `Test`.

Comment: @texasbruce that's because you're defining `ostream << string` in terms of `ostream << string`.

Comment: @texasbruce The proof of your assumption is wrong too. That works because by providing your own `ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, string s)` (which is not a function template!), you've taken template argument deduction out of the picture! So that operator makes it to overload resolution, and can be selected.

Comment: @Praetorian, Not to mention that the code is now invalid, which I believe means UB.

Comment: ["In the event that they edit the question to significantly change its meaning, after several answers have already been posted, it would be appropriate to roll back those edits"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148175/what-should-i-do-when-an-edit-would-change-the-context-of-a-question)

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for the headsup. I just added some additional info/tests I did which is related to this question... I hope its ok

Comment: @texasbruce: The assumption isn't "partially right and partially wrong"  it's entirely wrong. `string` has no implicit conversion to `const char*`, and the `const char*` overload is not used by `ostream<<string` at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck The right part is it does one conversion attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `explicit` keyword means you have to explicitly do the conversion yourself like `std::string(Test{})`. It disables implicit conversions.

```
cout << string{Test{}}; // <-- this is explicit, you've got implicit and explicit confused
```

The rule is, during template argument deduction, no user defined conversion is attemped. However, as you've noted if you only have a conversion operator to int it compiles. That is because that overload is not a function template. Take a look at the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), and you will see:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( int value );
```

This is a non-templated overload so the compiler will look for user defined conversions.

Comment: explicit and implicit always confused me... I removed the `explicit` keyword but it is still the same error. I don't think there is an `implicit` keyword right?

Comment: @texasbruce: Nope, `implicit` is implicit. ;)

Comment: Can you please take a look at my edit? I removed the keyword and it is still not working...

Comment: Even without the `explicit`, the code still doesn't compile. That's because there is no overload for `std::operator << (std::ostream &, Test &)`

Comment: @zindorsky That is correct. I thought the type conversion should implicitly work and convert to string so it can output.

Comment: @texasbruce But how would the compiler know that it was to convert to `string`? For example, what if your class also had an `operator int` or an `operator float`? All of those would work with `ostream`'s `operator <<` as well.

Comment: @texasbruce No conversion is attempted during template argument deduction, either you have an overload specifically for your type or you have to explicitly convert yourself to a type for which an overload exists.

Comment: @zindorsky It actually works if you only put a `operator int`. More overloading will cause `ambiguous overload` error. I only put a `operator string` there and expect it would work because a single `operator int` works.

Comment: @zindorsky Except an `operator int()` conversion operator [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6bd217eded935af0d02e514292889eb8-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62). That `operator<<` is not a function template so it makes it into the overload resolution set, and can be selected as a viable candidate. That's not the case with function templates, they never make it past the template argument deduction phase.

Comment: @Praetorian Ah, I did not know that about `operator int`. Thanks.

Comment: I got it working using two methods (in my edit), and you are right: a user defined conversion will be attempted. However only one conversion is attempted (such as from Test to int). If it requires 2 attempts (such as from Test to string to char*), it will not work..

Comment: @texasbruce Again, that's not what's going on here. Yes, there is a rule that two user defined conversions are not attempted, but in this case the `operator<<(ostream, string)` is not even *considered* by overload resolution; it gets tossed out earlier during template argument deduction.

Comment: @Borgleader: Er, the first time I read the answer either there was no mention of templates, or I missed it.  Downvote removed.  However, "The compiler won't attempt to convert it to string, because for example:" etc is still wrong.  The potential ambiguity is not the reason. [See?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ea76d03bfe756ec48bad89bf3d066939-cc73e281b3b6abc9bf6cf4f153b944a6)

Comment: @MooingDuck Not to mention there is [no ambiguity](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c54ebbfbd96f27f2fb91411be45fc5e6-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62). That part of the answer is incorrect.

Comment: This is more likely the reference?: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: @Praetorian I just re-read that part of my answer, and wow I really didn't explain what i was originally going for. I'll just remove that part.

Answer (score 2):

The `operator<<` overload that takes an `std::string` (or `std::basic_string`) is a function template. User defined conversions are not considered during template argument deduction, so the compiler doesn't think the `string` overload is a match.

To avoid the error, define an overload `basic_ostream& operator<<(basic_ostream&, Test&)` for your class.

Comment: Can you explain why Test object is not implicitly converted to string?

Comment: @texasbruce, This answer, his other comment, and the linked dupe all do.

Comment: Wow! Effective c++ says that implicit type conversion functions are ___never___ considered during template argument deduction.