# Why does the cast operator for my class not work with std::string?

Tags: c++, operators

I have a following class:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    operator value_type const& () const { return _val; }

private:
    value_type _val;
}
```

It's working with `std::ostream` when T is float, int etc.
But for `std::string` I have to do something like that:

```
std::cout << f.operator const std::string &();
```

So my question is why? I can do `std::cout << f` for `Foo<int>` but not for `Foo<std::string>`?;

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Mine works just fine.

Comment: *How* does it not work? Does it not compile? Is there any error? Is the result unexpected?

Comment: Show code that produces the error, and the error itself, complete and unedited.

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539555/why-does-outputting-a-class-with-a-conversion-operator-not-work-for-stdstring

Comment: The `operator<<` that takes a string is a template, and template argument deduction doesn't look through implicit conversions.

Comment: @chris sorry for that missunderstanding. I had something else in my mind when i was writing this question... Thanks for that link

Comment: What do you need both `T` and `value_type` for???

Comment: @barakmanos: It's very common to introduce a `value_type` member type into instantiations of class templates. You see it throughout the standard library, for example.

Comment: @barakmanos It's a fairly common method to allow other generic code with a template parameter `T = Foo<int>` (for example) to write `T::value_type`.

Comment: @barakmanos: `T` is only available within the template definition. The alias is available anywhere.