# How to filter input streamed to clog

Tags: c++, templates, filter, overloading, operator-keyword

I'am currently trying to filter input streamed to the 'clog' streambuffer. Therefore i wanted to create a class 'MyClog' which overloads it's << operator and filters the input streamed to it before forwarding the filtered input to the clog streambuffer.

The filtering depends on an internal state of the MyClog class. Also i want to overload the operator using a template, so i just have to implement one method.

example

```
clog << "This is a Test No." << 1;

myclog << "This is a Test No." << 2
```

Depending of the internal state of myclog the message is printed out via clog.

My overloaded operator works if i'am not using a template, what am i doing wrong? And what is the difference between `template<typename T>` and `template<class T>`?

Here is an excerpt of my code.

```
template<typename T>
class MyClog {

private:
bool state=false;

public:
MyClog& operator<<(const T& arg){
    if(state){
        clog << arg;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/q/6677072/560648?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`template<typename T>` is preferred over `template<class T>`, but they are equivalent.

You are templating the entire class when you only need to template one function - this should work:

```
class MyClog {

private:
bool state=false;

public:

template<typename T>
MyClog& operator<<(const T& arg){
    if(state){
        clog << arg;
    }
    return *this;
}
```