# Issue with std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, reference-wrapper

The issue is clear with the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  //std::vector<int> a, b;
  int a = 0, b = 0;
  auto refa = std::ref(a);
  auto refb = std::ref(b);
  std::cout << (refa < refb) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

If I use the commented `std::vector<int> a, b;` instead of `int a = 0, b = 0;`, then the code does not compile on any of GCC 5.1, clang 3.6, or MSVC'13. In my opinion, `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>` is implicitly convertible to `std::vector<int>&` which is LessThanComparable, and thus it should be LessThanComparable itself. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: _"`std::vector<int>&` which is LessThanComparable"_ Huh, really?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [really](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp).

Comment: @Barry: [It's actually not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) :P despite the operators.

Comment: What is the error message, OP?

Comment: Is the problem [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7505108/560648)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `no match for 'operator<'...`

Comment: Okay according to Barry it is indeed that. Good I feel happy now :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What is `TIL` short for? Sorry for my poor English...

Comment: @Lingxi **T**oday **I** **L**earned.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't understand, how can a type define a `<` operator and not be LessThanComparable?

Comment: @imreal The type doesn't define a `<` operator.  It is a non member function

Comment: @imreal: I don't know. It surprises me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't see it in the link you provided, did I miss something?

Comment: @imreal: What don't you see?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Something that indicates that `vector` is not LessThanComparable in this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @imreal: Well, um, there's a list of concepts whose requirements it means and _LessThanComparable_ is not one of them?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh yeah, I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is that the non-member [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) for `std::vector` is a function template:

```
template< class T, class Alloc >
bool operator<( const vector<T,Alloc>& lhs,
                const vector<T,Alloc>& rhs );
```

Implicit conversions are **not** considered when doing template type deduction here, [temp.arg.explicit] emphasis on if:

> Implicit conversions (Clause 4) will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the
>   corresponding function parameter **if** the parameter type contains no *template-parameters* that participate
>   in template argument deduction.

But in this case, the parameter type does participate in deduction. That's why it can't be found. Had we written our own *non*-template `operator<`:

```
bool operator<(const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs)
{
    return true;
}
```

Your code would work as expected. To use the generic one though, you will have to explicitly pull out the reference:

```
std::cout << (refa.get() < refb.get()) << '\n';
```

Comment: Very interesting. What is the rationale for the part of the spec that you quoted?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677072/overload-resolution-failure-when-streaming-object-via-implicit-conversion-to-str/7505108#comment9064889_6677134

Comment: If `operator<` was written as a `friend bool` Koenig operator, would it be found by conversion?  I'm wondering if this is a matter of "vector is old, they didn't know the right way" or "pseudo-references are hard, reference wrapper should add SFINAE detecting overloads" (probably both).

Comment: @Yakk As a non-template (e.g. `friend bool operator<(const vector& lhs, const vector& rhs) { ... }`), yes it would be found.

Comment: @Barry Shouldn't `friend bool operator<(const vector& lhs, const vector& rhs) { ... }` still be a template?

Comment: @lingxi no.  It is a non-template function that can only be found via ADL.  In fewer words, Koenig operators are magic.

Comment: @Barry I believe it.  I was just concerned that the conversion operators wouldn't cause ADL to kick off in the context of the result type (I could not remember if they first find overloads, then do conversion or look at all conversions, and overloads for each conversion).  Gah, template conversion operators doing Koenig lookup?  I can't see how it would be possible, but not certain where it falls apart.  Anyhow, this is a tangent.

Comment: @Yakk Thought I'd [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30265207/2069064) the obvious followup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that

> ```
> std::vector<int> a, b;
> ```

Is doing what it is supposed to?  Take this for example

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a, b;
  //int a = 0, b = 0;
  a.push_back(42);
  a.push_back(6);
  a.push_back(15);
  for (int ii=0; ii<43; ii++) {
    b.push_back(ii);
  }
  auto refa = std::ref(a);
  auto refb = std::ref(b);
  std::cout<<&refa<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<&refb<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Contents of vector A"<<std::endl;
  for(auto n : a)
  {
    std::cout<<' '<<n;
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl<<"Contents of vector b: ";
  for (auto n : b){
    std::cout<<' '<<n;
  }
  //std::cout << (refa < refb) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Which results in

```
0x7fff5fbff0c0
0x7fff5fbff0b8
Contents of vector A
 42 6 15
Contents of vector b:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
```

Ultimately

```
std::vector<int> a, b;
```

Creates two separate vectors of integers called a and b, both of which have no contents; this is not how one would declare a single vector with members a and b.

```
int a=0, b=0;
```

Declares two separate integers called a and b, which each have a value of 0.  Those two code snippets declare completely different variables and should not be used interchangeably.