# Succinct implementation of min() that returns minimum of multiple values

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, min, template-meta-programming

With `std::min()`, we can `std::min(a, b)`. But, what if I want `min(a, b, c)` or `min(a, b, c, d, e)`? I know the following implementation works:

```
template <typename T>
const T& min(const T& x, const T& y) {
  return x < y ? x : y;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
const T& min(const T& x, const T& y, const Ts&... xs) {
  return min(min(x, y), xs...);
}
```

But I want a single succinct function (provided that it's possible at all, of course). I've tried the following

```
using std::swap;
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
const T& min(const T& x, const T& y, const Ts&... xs) {
  return min(min(x, y), xs...);
}
```

This does not work with `min(1, 2, 3)`. This issue can be solved if I can just import a specific overload of `std::swap()`, which unfortunately doesn't seem possible in current C++. So, I'm asking, is there a succinct implementation that achieves what I want with just a single function? Note that I'm considering up to C++14. No C++1z please.

Comment: Why not use `std::min({a, b, c})`, `std::min({a, b, c, d, e})`, etc.? This works out of the box and is constexpr.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with your first version. Why the restriction of a single function? Bear in mind that it is a template and will generate a function for each call (with different `Ts`), so this restriction seems pointless.

Comment: @ildjarn What if `a`, `b`, `c`, etc are expensive to copy, or are simply non-copyable?

Comment: @Lingxi : In that case, given `using std::cref;`, `std::min({cref(a), cref(b), cref(c)})`, etc.

Comment: @ildjarn I would say `min(a, b, c)` is much better than `min({cref(a), cref(b), cref(c)})`. Moreover, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b64645bd0e087f98) does not work.

Comment: @ildjarn The issue is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30263007/1348273).

Comment: `min({cref(a), cref(b), cref(c)}, std::less<std::common_type_t<decltype(a), decltype(b), decltype(c)>>{})` or simply `std::less<decltype(a)>` since you know the types are the same, and the initializer_list would give an error if they aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bite:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<template<typename> class CompT = std::less, typename T, typename... Ts>
T const& variadic_min(T const& a, T const& b, Ts const&... ts) {
    return std::min({ std::cref(a), std::cref(b), std::cref(ts)... }, CompT<T>{});
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b469d4fe42a18f)</kbd>

One could also add an appropriate `static_assert` to improve the error message in the case that not all types are the same.

Comment: Ingenious! It also allows certain degree of customization on the predicate. There are a few minor issues, though. [This](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility/blob/master/cppu/algorithm.hpp#L70) should be the version to be shipped.

Comment: @Lingxi : Pedantically, that allows a single-argument invocation (which doesn't make sense), and what's being supplied is a comparator, not a predicate. ;-]

Comment: Pedantically, since `std::min()` allows it, so should we ;-]

Comment: @Lingxi : Fair enough!

Comment: Not to mention the mathematical notions on partially ordered sets, which allow for sets of one element. Solid answer though.

Comment: If you are interested in writing trinkets like this, feel free to join the [party](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility) and play together :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
auto lst = {4, 3, 1, 2, 5};
auto iter = std::min_element(std::begin(lst), std::end(lst));
std::cout << *iter << '\n'; // 1
```